# mysql trigger auto calculate age from dob and create age field insert data

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example
     BEFORE INSERT ON dates FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     declare age int;
          IF ((set age = AND (select * , year(curdate())-year(dob) ) < 18)
          THEN
               CALL `'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type'`;
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```

Comment: That's some code, but what's the associated question?

Comment: why add  an age field  if you have dob  ..  ???  you can calculate each time you need  with a simple query  ..